# recursive angular div template

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

https://stackblitz.com/github/skwallace36/famtree

look at the nodes component... and see how the css is messed up with my current recurisve implementation

so I've looked around and only found good recursive directives for UL and LI... I think this is just because UL and LI and commonly nested. I am using the most current version of angular

I am trying to use recursion to take some json data in an angular component and put it into divs like the following...

does anyone know how I would translate the node list into a recursive angular directive so that I can re use the html for different values of node? I think that I might have to have a ngif in there to detect if it has children or not so that it can either be nested in a parent or child div.

the basic html is 
hv-item
    hv-item-parent
    hv-item-children
        hv-item-child
           ***another hv-item recursed
        hv-item-child
        hv-item-child

sos send help

```js
public node = [
    {name: 'production', children: [
      {name: 'test one', children: [
        {name: 'development one', children: []},
        {name: 'development two', children: []}
      ]}
      ,
      {name: 'test two', children: [
        {name: 'development three', children: []},
        {name: 'development four', children: []}
      ]}
    ]}
  ];
```

```html
<div class="hv-container">
      <div class="hv-wrapper">

          <!-- Key component -->
          <div class="hv-item">

              <div class="hv-item-parent">
                  <p class="simple-card"> Parent </p>
              </div>

              <div class="hv-item-children">

                  <div class="hv-item-child">
                      <!-- Key component -->
                      <div class="hv-item">

                          <div class="hv-item-parent">
                              <p class="simple-card"> Parent </p>
                          </div>

                          <div class="hv-item-children">

                              <div class="hv-item-child">
                                  <p class="simple-card"> Child 1 </p>
                              </div>

                              <div class="hv-item-child">
                                  <p class="simple-card"> Child 2 </p>
                              </div>

                              <div class="hv-item-child">
                                  <p class="simple-card"> Child 2 </p>
                              </div>

                          </div>

                      </div>
                  </div>

                  <div class="hv-item-child">
                      <p class="simple-card"> Child 2 </p>
                  </div>

                  <div class="hv-item-child">
                      <p class="simple-card"> Child 3 </p>
                  </div>

              </div>

          </div>

      </div>
  </div>
```

```
<div class="hv-container">
  <div class="hv-wrapper">
    <div *ngFor="let node of nodelist">
      <div class="hv-item">
        <div *ngIf="node.children.length > 0">
            <div class="hv-item-parent">
              <p class="simple-card"> {{node.name}} </p>
            </div>
            <div class="hv-item-children">
              <app-nodes [nodelist]=node.children></app-nodes>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div *ngIf="node.children.length === 0">
          <div class="hv-item-child">
            <p class="simple-card"> {{node.name}} </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

how about this - copied / modified from [here](https://gist.github.com/arniebradfo/5cf89c362cc216df6fc1d9ca4d536b72).  This is slightly different from @chris-farmer.  I think this would limit then amount of code that runs the recursion and also give you more control over the template variables - since only the "Recursive" part of the template is repeated and not the entire component.

```
<ng-template #recursiveNodes let-nodes>
 <div *ngFor="let item of nodes">
    {{item.name}}
    <div *ngIf="item.children.length > 0">
    <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="recursiveNodes; context: {$implicit: item.children}"></ng-container>
    </div>
  </div>
</ng-template>
<ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="recursiveNodes;context:{$implicit: nodes}"></ng-container>
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this?  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-recurs-componetn?file=src/app/app.component.html

In your main app component where `node` is defined:

```
<mycomponent 
    *ngFor="let item of node"
    [data]="item">
</mycomponent>
```

In the `mycomponent` component:

```
<div>Name: {{ data.name }}</div>
<div *ngIf="data.children" style="margin-left: 20px;">
  <mycomponent 
      [data]="item" 
      *ngFor="let item of data.children">
  </mycomponent>
</div>
```

Of course you can add complexity and formatting as required, but this shows how you could reuse the `mycomponent` component from within `mycomponent` itself.

Comment: current I have (see above) @chris_farmer

Comment: I added it to the end of my post... it messes up the css formatting though. does it look like it is achieving my goal?

Comment: this is painful.. I believe that it is messing up because the css uses before and after

Comment: Create a demo of this in stackblitz so others can more easily see and edit your work to help.

Comment: @StuartWallace There's an error with loading the stackblitz.

Comment: I was trying to clean it up... wow I'm struggling.... try this one https://stackblitz.com/github/skwallace36/famtree

Comment: my recursive implementation has messed up the left branch lines and the space of the root element (too high)

Comment: actually it has just messed up the drawing of lines between nodes in general

Comment: @StuartWallace check this https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-hd8zun-hs3omx

Answer (score 0):

There is an example for your three-level nested JSON object 'node'

```
<div *ngFor="let item of node">
<div class="hv-item-parent">
  <p class="simple-card"> {{item.name}} </p>
</div>
<div *ngFor="let nested of item.children" class="hv-item-children">{{nested.name}}
  <div *ngFor="let secondNested of nested.children" class="hv-item-children">{{secondNested.name}}</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have tried answering your duplicate question 
[recursive angular messing up css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51252413/recursive-angular-messing-up-css/51255625#51255625)

[Solution](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-hd8zun-hs3omx) on Stackblitz

Comment: you sir are a god.... and yeah I wanted to delete this question because it got so ugly