# recursive angular messing up css

Tags: html, css, angular, sass

hello I am building a family tree diagram based on https://github.com/zikosichi/hierarchy-view

my current implementation resides here

https://stackblitz.com/github/skwallace36/famtree

my recursive angular implementation in nodes.component.html is messing up the css. the lines between nodes are being drawn incorrectly...

is it my implementation of the recursion, the css, or both?

I am desperate to figure this out

thank you so much for checking this out

Comment: While rendering a component in a loop, you have to make sure the component has only those html that should be repeated.

Answer (score 1):

While rendering a component in a loop, you have to make sure the component has only those html that has to be repeated, and not those which should not be repeated.

In your case, `<app-nodes>` component was repeated in a loop.
The component has `<div class="hv-container">` and `<div class="hv-wrapper">` which gets repeated.

Only the items and other child elements must be repeated.

Have split the `app-nodes` to another containing only child items named `<app-node>`

The forked [Solution](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-hd8zun-hs3omx) is available here

Comment: this was KILLING me - how do I accept this answer? or do I just upvote